# Adding a cookie to a WLResourceRequest

Tags: cookies, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Siteminder for Authentication, once it is successfully Authenticated by Siteminder, it will return us the cookies (which will be used for Authorization) as header param.

I'm trying to add these cookies with the WLResourceRequest API for Authorization but my code doesn't seem to send any cookie and giving me "Authorization Failure"

**Code used to add cookie using WLClient**

```
WLClient.getInstance().addGlobalHeader("Cookie", cookies);
```

I even tried to add the cookie before WLResourceRequest call,

```
 request.addHeader("Cookie", cookies);
```

I can see the cookies has been added to the header but when I try to use that header param for Authorization, it is getting failed

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the Cookie as a header to your WLResourceRequest itself.

Please refer to the API documentation [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLResourceRequest.html).
Look for the setHeader() method.